# EJB package import vs resource injection

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, import, ejb

I'm new to EJB, and there's something about resource injection that has been bugging me for a while. I guess this is a pretty basic concept, but I couldn't figure it out on my own. And people say that there's no dumb question so here it goes:

What I don't understand is the difference between Package Import and Resource Injection. The difference I refer is not about usage (they sure are used in different way), but about meaning. Why doesn't EJB use package import instead of resource injection?

For example I have a **getInfoBean** that implements interface **getInfo**. To use this bean in a client, I can lookup in JNDI or DI with @EJB (if client's deployed in ACC). In either way, I need to specify the name getInfo. So while doesn't EJB let **import** handle this? Isn't the purpose of **import** is to specify some name so it can make the program aware of the class or interface that it'd like to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The import `import some.package.getInfoBean` in your client would 1) bind the client to the specific instance of that bean and 2) DI happens at runtime and enables the container to intercept all calls to the EJB to, i.e. managed declarative transactions.

So, the *compiler* requires the `import` statements to know against which classes to build the byte code. DI is a runtime feature enabling the JVM to perform certain (often complex) things before, during or after the call to an injected resource.

**EDIT:** Nowadays, annotations are used for DI in Java. Neverthess, this does not mean that all annotations are related to DI. For example `@Override` does not influence runtime behaviour , as indicated by the annotation `@Retention(value=SOURCE)` it only deals with source code. Whereas the [`@EJB`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/EJB.html) annotation is accessible during runtime as indicated by the `@Retention(value=RUNTIME)` annotation on the annotation itself. This annotation is a DI *enabler*.

Comment: So basically import is something done in compile time, whilst DI is done in runtime. Is that right?